# Ubuntu 20.04 Slack 4.15.0 not using system proxy on VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, slack

When on my vpn (connected with openconnect), I require an http proxy to access the internet.

I have the system proxy configured to use wpad, and I know this works because firefox is set to use the system proxy, and it works both on and off of the VPN without changing any network settings.

So can Slack 4.15.0 use this system wide proxy setting and if so how? (This works fine on a different system running slack 4.14.0)

If slack cannot use the system wide proxy settings, can I configure slack to manually specify a proxy? I see older posts that suggest starting slack from the CLI using a `--proxy-server` option, but that option appears to not be available in 4.15. And I can't find any way to set it in the /etc/slack.conf file either.

How can I use this latest version of slack on my VPN?

EDIT: Upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04, and still see the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I contacted slack support and resolved this by doing the following.

- Remove the slack package installed from the ubuntu repo.
- Remove the snap that the above package seems to install.
- Download the .deb from the slack website.
- Manually install the .deb downloaded from the slack website.

Comment: it doesn't work even from .dep

Comment: It worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04. I had to restart my computer to make this work. For some reason slack from snap was still running even after its removal and slack app restart.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me, also on 20.04.